# Complex Phasors Vs Real Vectors

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, fourier-analysis

I know how to analyze AC circuits in the complex plane. The complex plane makes analysis of these circuits easier. I understand the concept of using differential equations to solve for these functions in the time domain. My professors explains this plane and these phasors are vectors with magnitudes, but I'm sure there not vectors, because dot products and cross products  would give different results. So basically how can taking a vectors make them a complex number make a circuit easier, because if you tried to do the mathematical operations we perform on these phasors with real vectors we would get entirely different results  (incorrect results) right? I have yet to see a proof that analyzing circuits this way gives the correct results. Like I can divide complex numbers to solve for voltage or current, but I would not be able to do this with a vector.

Comment: Can you give an example to show what you mean by "...if you tried to do the mathematical operations we perform on these phasors with real vectors we would get entirely different results..."?

Answer (score 0):

Vectors are not only real valued, the vector space definitions work fine for complex valued vectors too.

With Admittance Matrix circuit descriptions the matrix elements are complex valued with L, C circuit components, the node voltage vector's and branch current vector's components become complex valued too.

But you are right that complex numbers, the complex plane are not the same as real valued 2D vectors, the Cartesian plane.

Hestenes' rebooting of Grassman/Clifford "Geometric Algebra" shows real valued vectors playing nicely with "complex numbers"

In 2D GA real valued 2-vectors can be multiplied and divided, the general result being isomorphic to complex numbers.  The GA "complex numbers" multiply and divide as usual, their products with real valued vectors result in rotated/scaled real valued vectors.

Lots of GA intros on the web, if not making much headway in being taught

https://www.google.com/search?q=geometric+algebra&oq=geometric+algebra